# Creating Menus in the project and files panes in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to create a simple module in netbeans that can check in and check out files in netbeans.  However I don't understand how I can create menu item in the project and files popup menus like subversion does.  can anyone please help.

Regards,

Sunil

Answer (score 1):

Have a Look at the [Actions: How to add things to Files, Folders, Menus, Toolbars and more](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansDeveloperFAQ#Actions%3a_How_to_add_things_to_Files.2C_Folders.2C_Menus.2C_Toolbars_and_more) section of the [NetBeans Developer FAQ](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansDeveloperFAQ) that should point you in the right direction.